# status of php, curl session

Tags: php, session, cookies, curl

I am going to logged in a web site using curl. Its going to logged in fine. Now I want to know the status of session, that it is alive or not. Because user may send request for different pages after logging in.  My code is here. thanks

```
$url="https://mywebsite.com/login.pl";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "username=xxxxxx&passwd=xxxxx&client=xxxxx");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 4);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
$store = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to grab cookies and use 'em in your next request, something like:

```
curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_COOKIE,         $cookie); 
curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,    true); 
curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION,  true); 
curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,    false); 
curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false); 
curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT,  true); 
curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_HEADER,         false); 
curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_POST,           false); 
curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$result = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: what does you mean by 'em. secondly how I will come to know that session is alive or dead. So I can know, would I need to reconnect or not.